# need driver for dell printer V515w

Tags: 12.04

I need to have a driver to run my dell V515w printer,scanner,fax.

Comment: When your Linux system is plugged into the Dell V515w, what happens? Does the Linux system recognize the hardware? What Linux distro/type/version/form are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Dell has a driver, but they don't list 12.04.  You can try using it, and see if it works.

**Note:** The driver has 32-bit support only.

Installation Instructions:

1. Do not attach the printer via USB to the Linux machine.
2. Extract the driver file file.
3. Run the installer script file by double-clicking on the file icon and
   then click the `Run in Terminal` button or run the script file via command-line.
4. Follow the instructions in the installer screen.<sup>[Dell](http://ftp.us.dell.com/printer/V515W_Readme.txt)</sup>

Click [Here](http://downloads.dell.com/printer/R247655.tar.gz) to download the driver.

[image]

[image]

[image]